# Falta de tradução para "Isto é comentário sobre outra publicação, não uma resposta."

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução

O comentário que aparece por baixo desta opção regrediu, i.e, esta em inglês novamente.

<kbd>[image: Erro na tradução de um dos itens da fila de analise]</kbd>

Comment: Como acessamos esse formulário de comentários prontos? Eu não achei em lugar nenhum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Novo texto](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-pt/translate/#pt_BR/english/78045029):

> Isto não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver reputação suficiente, você vai poder deixar comentários em qualquer post mas, até lá, escreva apenas resposta que não dependam de mais informações de quem perguntou.

Comment: Gabe, esse texto já estava traduzido, mas ficou em inglês novamente há pouco tempo. Acredito que tenha relação com algumas atualizações feitas no site em fevereiro(Alguns menus mudaram).

Comment: O texto antigo era esse: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele - você sempre pode comentar em suas próprias publicações e quando tiver [pontos de reputação](/help/whats-reputation) suficientes você poderá [comentar sobre qualquer publicação](/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @DiegoF sim, mas a tradução antiga era sobre o texto antigo, que era diferente desse atual. Foi essa mudança que fez voltar pro inglês. O texto novo não tinha tradução, até agora

Comment: O texto novo é bem melhor